# Flask not reacting to code changes

Tags: python, flask

I am new to Flask and am implementing a tiny application. I successfully got it to display "Hello World" when visiting a certain web page, but I cannot change it to say "Hello World Again," even if I change the code. Why is it still running the old code and how can I get it to run the new code? Thanks.

Comment: Try to reload the page using Shift + F5.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to [run the app in debug mode](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#debug-mode):

```
app.debug = True
app.run()
```

or

```
app.run(debug=True)
```

But remember, only do that in your development environment:

> Even though the interactive debugger does not work in forking environments (which makes it nearly impossible to use on production servers), it still allows the execution of arbitrary code. **This makes it a major security risk and therefore it must never be used on production machines.**

You could also use `use_reloader=True` without enabling debug mode, but that's not a good idea since you really want the debugger during development.